# Matrix representation of a polynomial mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Let $V:= \Bbb R[t]_{≤4}$ (the vector field of real polynomials of
>   degree 4 or lower) and $$f: V \to V$$ $$P = \sum_{i=0}^4 a_it^i
>  \mapsto P(t+1):= \sum_{i=0}^4 a_i(t+1)^i  $$ Furthermore let K is the
>   standard basis of V
>
> - find $M_K(f)$ (the matrix representation of f in respect to the basis K)

Ok, in this case, $K = (1,t,t^2,t^3,t^4)$

What I normally to find representation Matrices do is find f(*insert basis vectors here*) and plot them in a Matrix. In this case I do not understand how exactly the function works, do I have to find $f(1),f(t),f(t^2), ...? $ That doesn't seem to make sense...

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f$ applied to a polynomial $p(t)$ returns the polynomial $p(t+1)$ (where, instead of plugging $t$ into the polynomial, we plug in $t + 1$). For example, applying the map to the basis elements results in:

$$ f(1) = 1, \\
f(t) = (t + 1), \\
f(t^2) = (t + 1)^2, \\
f(t^3) = (t + 1)^3, \\
f(t^4) = (t + 1)^4. $$

You can expand each term and express it in terms of the basis elements and this will give you the required matrix.

Comment: Ah I see, so i.e the first column vector would be (1 0 0 0 0) and the 5th one would be (1 4 6 4 1)   (given that $(t +1)^4) = t^4+4 t^3+6 t^2+4 t+1$ ?

Comment: @TravisPetit: Yep.